# How to write a quoted text in a variable of type string?

Tags: javascript

I need to write a text that has quotation marks in a variable. The problem is that this text is only recorded when I remove them. I want all characters (including quotation marks) to be interpreted as being a common string.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function txt(){
            var a = "  "text1" text2  "text3" ";
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Escape the double quotes or enclose the text in single quotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a combo of single and double quotes:

```js
var a = '  "text1" text2  "text3" ';
console.log(a);
```

Escape the quotes:

```js
var a = "  \"text1\" text2  \"text3\" ";
console.log(a)
```

Use newer [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```js
var a = `  "text1" text2  "text3" `;
console.log(a);
```

Comment: Sensational! In addition to solving the problem, I realized that `` text1 'text2' text3 `` can be written in several lines of the code, rather than just one.

Answer (score 0):

Escape the quote by back slash.

> We can use the backslash ( \ ) escape character to prevent JavaScript from interpreting a quote as the end of the string. The syntax of \' will always be a single quote, and the syntax of \" will always be a double quote, without any fear of breaking the string.

```js
var a = "  \"text1\" text2  \"text3\" ";
console.log(a);
```

You also can use single quote to wrap the whole string and use double quote without escaping. Example:

```js
var a = '  "text1" text2  "text3" ';
console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var a = "  \"text1\" text2  \"text3\" ";
```